# Is there any method for fix manually an Alloy Analyzer graph?

Tags: graph, analyzer, alloy

I need to fix my Alloy graph, for example I have this output:

[image: Graph]

I can't move "node2" rectangle over the row of "node0" and "node1", and I can't move "node1" under "node2" whitout also move "node0". Is there any solution? Thank you.

PS: I am using Alloy Analyzer 4.2 under Windows.

PPS:  This is only an example, i get a big graph with 5 or 6 rows of 20-25 rectangles, and if I can't fix it manually, it's only a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the direct question:  I for one have never found a way to make the visualizer change its mind about which nodes should be on the same horizontal level.  (That doesn't quite mean it's not possible, but it does mean that if it's possible it's not immediately obvious how to do it.  But I guess you knew that already.)

If your goal is to make the auto-generated diagrams easier to read, the simplest approach is to experiment with adjustments to the visualizer theme.  The "Magic Layout" button can be helpful; manual adjustments to hide some nodes or display some relations as labels rather than arcs can help with diagrams which are otherwise too cluttered.

If your goal is to make a 'good' version of a diagram for inclusion on a slide for a talk or a figure for a paper, you may want to export to Dot and import into a graph-drawing tool that gives you the kind of manual control you want (or edit the .dot file yourself, if you are familiar with graphviz and can make it do what you want), or export to XML and generate the graph description language of your choice from the XML.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Lightning tool is an Ecplise plugin relying on Alloy4.2 to formally define Domain Specific Languages and might be a solution to your problem.

It's still under development, but if you are only interested in being able to freely reorganize each atom and label of generated instances, there shouldn't be any problems, as it uses Ecplise draw2D to render those latter.

If now you're really interested in providing an intuitive visualization to your generated instance (by intuitive I mean a visualization that is closer to its domain rather than the structure of your model), then you can define your own language (with your model as abstract syntax ) and define a concrete syntax for it.

The update site to be used for the installation of the tool is : http://lightning.gforge.uni.lu/update-site

Don't hesitate to contact me if you plan to give it a shot and get any issues.
(I'm eager of constructive feedbacks ;-) )

The steps to follow to generate a graphical instance in which any components can be moved are :

1. Install Lightning
2. Create a new Lightning Project
3. Create a new Language in this project
4. Put your model in the ASM folder
5. generate instances of the language by "running the project"